# How to check the first duplicate in a word php?

Tags: php

I have this word.

```
AGHIJKLAL
```

I need to search the **first duplicate word** from that string the answer is `A`, because the word that duplicate in those sentences is `A` word.

So for example.

**INPUT 0**

```
JKLMKL
```

**OUTPUT 0**

```
K
```

**INPUT 1**

```
nmopqrqn
```

**OUTPUT 1**

```
q
```

I have made this program.

```
<?php 

$input = fgets(STDIN);
$rows = str_split(trim($input));
$arr = array();
$index = 0;

while (True) {
    $reset = False;
    $ind = 0;
    foreach ($rows as $row => $val) {
    if(!isset($rows[$row+1])){
        continue;
    }
      if($rows[0] !== $rows[$row+1]) {
        $reset = True;
        continue;
      } else {
          $reset = True;
          $arr[$index] = $rows[0];
          $index++;
          break;
      }
    }
    if (!$reset) {
        break; # break out of the while(true)
    }else{
        unset($rows[0]);
        $rows = array_values($rows);
    }
    # otherwise the foreach loop is `reset`
}

echo "{$arr[0]} \n";

?>
```

But when i used the **INPUT 1** value, it returns `n` value. What could go wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, convert string into array using `str_split()` and check each character.

```
//convert string into array
$strArr = str_split('AGHIJKLAL'); 

$temp = []; //temporary array  
foreach($strArr as $v){
    //check each character if it is in temp array or  not, if yes, character matched and exit from loop using break; 
    if(in_array($v, $temp)){
        $repeatChar = $v;
        break;
    }else{ // if not matched store character into temp array.
        $temp[] = $v;
    }
}
echo $repeatChar;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/utjU2)

Comment: could you please, give some explanation about your code ?